# Deleted analysis in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Can I recover a deleted analysis in quicksight or can I copy it from its dashboard?
Is there any way I can do it?

In quicksight documentation there is a way to recover a schedule for deletion analysis, but there is nothing about a normal user deletion.
I moved the analysis to a shared folder and then I had to remove it from there but didn't realize there is no other copy of that analysis. The analysis has a dashboard, but I can't find a way to reverse engineer it back to analysis without starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I recall that once deleted, they are subject to a default 30 day recovery period  via API.  See the following for details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/developerguide/restore-analysis.html